# Perl - Script to concatenate metrics in files by common dimensions

Tags: perl, concatenation, metrics, dimensions

I want to concatenate the metrics from 3 files into 1 files based on common dimensions.

Eg:

```
File 1:
A B C 10 20
A D C 30 40
```

```
File 2:
A B C 100 200
A D C 300 400
```

```
File 3:
A B C 1000
A D C 3000
```

```
Output File:
A B C 10 20 100 200 1000
A D C 30 40 300 400 3000
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a hash, where every key is first 3 fields from the file input, and iterate through every file pushing the values into an array which is the value of the hash.
Please let me know whether you would like to see actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need perl for this.  Here's a 2 line shell script that works:

```
join file1 file2 | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\) [A-Z] [A-Z] /\1 /g' > file4
join file3 file4 | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\) [A-Z] [A-Z] /\1 /g' > file5
```

file5 has your output data